# (Oracle SQL) Need to get the startdate and enddate of a date column and return dates for each day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date column and I need to return each day from the start date to the end date. For example if I have a date column that starts at `01-01-2020` till `22/03/2022`. Then I want to return data such as:

| DateColumn |
| --- |
| 01-JAN-20 |
| 02-JAN-20 |
| 03-JAN-20 |
| and so on...... |
| until 22-MAR-22 |

Comment: So I have checked I can use the MIN and MAX functions to get the earliest and latest dates but still trying to work out the answer

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12:

```sql
SELECT t.id, d.day
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT t.start_date + LEVEL - 1 AS day
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY t.start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= t.end_date
       ) d
WHERE  t.start_date <= t.end_date
```

Before Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT t.id, d.COLUMN_VALUE AS day
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT t.start_date + LEVEL - 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY t.start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= t.end_date
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
         )
       ) d
WHERE  t.start_date <= t.end_date
```

Or:

```sql
WITH dates (id, day, end_date) AS (
  SELECT id, start_date, end_date
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  start_date <= end_date
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, day + 1, end_date
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  day + 1 <= end_date
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id, day SET ord
SELECT id, day
FROM   dates;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2022-03-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-10' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | ID | DAY |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-21 |
> | 1 | 02-JAN-21 |
> | ... | ... |
> | 1 | 21-MAR-22 |
> | 1 | 22-MAR-22 |
> | 2 | 01-JAN-22 |
> | 2 | 02-JAN-22 |
> | ... | ... |
> | 2 | 09-JAN-22 |
> | 2 | 10-JAN-22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=06ccfb01b8bae4d34df9692873c2f63c)*

Answer (score 0):

One option might also be

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (id, start_date, end_date)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2022-03-22' FROM DUAL)
  5      SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1 datecolumn
  6        FROM test
  7  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_date - start_date + 1
  8    ORDER BY datecolumn;

DATECOLUMN
----------
01.01.2020
02.01.2020
03.01.2020
04.01.2020
<snip>
14.03.2022
15.03.2022
16.03.2022
17.03.2022
18.03.2022
19.03.2022
20.03.2022
21.03.2022
22.03.2022

812 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If there - as MT0 commented - is more than a single row in that table that contains start/end dates, then

```
WITH
   test (id, start_date, end_date)
   AS
      (SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2022-03-22' FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 2, DATE '2022-03-15', DATE '2022-03-23' FROM DUAL)
  SELECT id, start_date + COLUMN_VALUE - 1 datecolumn
    FROM test
         CROSS JOIN
         TABLE (
            CAST (
               MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
                               FROM DUAL
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_date - start_date + 1)
                  AS SYS.odcinumberlist))
ORDER BY id, datecolumn;
```

Comment: If there is more than one row of input then this will generate exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate rows as there is no way of correlating each row of the hierarchy to the previous row of the hierarchy so, instead, each row will be correlated to all rows at the previous level and as the level increase so does the number of duplicate paths.

Comment: Certainly, **if** there is ... But, there's no evidence that there actually *is*. Or *is not* :) But OK, I posted similar code that deals with it.

Comment: Thanks brilliant got it to work. so in row 2 i removed the id, in row 4 i removed the 1 and in the hardcoded values i put in min and max functions to my date column then instead of from dual i put in my table name and it worked thanks I would accept this as an answer but don't know how lol and my reputation isn't high enough to uptick your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. As of accepting/upvoting, there's the green tick mark on left hand side of each answer (and those up/down arrows).

Comment: Yeh I did uptick your answer but it won't show it on the page due to my reputation being too low.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PIPELINED function, where you can just plug in the dates you want

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN nt_date PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
BEGIN
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_start);
    EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
    v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END generate_dates_pipelined;
/

SELECT
        c.COLUMN_VALUE 
  FROM   
TABLE(generate_dates_pipelined(DATE '2022-01-01',
DATE '2022-01-30')) c
```